# Is memento(te) semantically a future imperative?

Tags: semantics, imperative, irregular-words, future-tense

The verb *meminisse* is irregular.
It has only the active perfect system (*memini, meministi, meminit…*) and the imperatives *memento* and *mementote*.
These imperatives are future imperatives by form, and I would like to know if they are future by meaning, too.

Regular verbs have present and future imperatives (eg. *ama(te)* and *amato(te)*) and there is a semantic difference between the two.
The verb *meminisse* has only one type of imperative, which is of future form.
**Is *memento(te)* semantically present or future imperative?**
Or perhaps it is both or we cannot tell.
I do not recall ever seeing a discussion about this.

The imperative *memento* came up in two questions recently:
[Negative Future Imperatives](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2343/79) and [Parallels for the infinitive in “memento mori”?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2230/79).

Comment: Grammatically it is a future imperative. Semantically, the answer is in the question of Sapphira : http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2343/negative-future-imperatives

>future imperatives are used when the command is given for some point in the future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mementō is formed from the reduplicated perfect stem (IE *me-mn-), not from the present stem (IE *men-). Thus, morphologically it is a perfect imperative, not a future imperative; the latter is always formed from the present stem. The IE imperative ending *-tōd has various different usages in the daughter languages: Greek -τω forms the 3rd sing. present imperative, -σατω the 3rd sing. aorist imperative. memini is a perfect-present (perfect in form, but present in meaning), so there is no reason not to regard mementō as a perfect imperative in form, but present imperative in meaning.

Comment: This was enlightening. Thank you! I had considered *-to* to be a future imperative ending, not a general imperative ending. (This is a side effect of not having a wider IE background to Latin.) I asked a [separate question about perfect imperatives](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2349/79) because it made me curious.

Comment: To complicate matters, though, the PIE ending * -tōd does seem to have been specifically a future imperative -- at least, its reflexes in both Latin and Vedic function as such (though not in Greek, where the 3sg pres. meaning appears to be innovative). In which case *mementō* might be described as a future imperative built on the perfect stem (which in this verb has a quasi-present meaning).

Comment: @TKR. The Vedic "imperative II" in -tāt is not exclusively future in meaning according to current indological thinking. The score is thus 2 (Greek and Vedic) to 1 (Latin). There is of course something intrinsically futuristic about any imperative (you are ordering someone to do something that has not yet happened).

Comment: I don't know enough about Vedic usage to know how well the two languages compare, but the same could be said of Latin -- e.g. *scito* normally means "know (right now)", not "know (at some future time)". But as you say, it's difficult to draw clear boundaries given the nature of imperatives.