# Are there other perfect imperatives than memento?

Tags: example-request, verbs, imperative, irregular-words

I learned from [this previous question about the semantics of *memento(te)*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2345/79) that *memento(te)* is not morphologically a future imperative.
It turned to be a perfect imperative (semantically present), as it was formed from the perfect stem.
I had previously thought of *-to* as a future imperative ending exclusively.
I would like to know how unique *memento(te)* is in Latin.

Are there other examples of perfect imperatives than *memento(te)*?
Or are there any other examples if imperatives ending in *-to(te)* than the usual future imperatives, perfect or not?

Such forms are not found in conjugation tables — or they have magically evaded my sight — but there might be some rare occurrences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The perfect imperative is effectively extinct in Latin. I have never seen it with a perfect meaning, and in fact did not realize that *mementō* was based on a perfect stem until fdb pointed it out (though in retrospect the reduplication and perfect endings are a pretty good clue).

The best place to look for evidence would be defective verbs, which might not have a present imperative available to replace the perfect.

There are three Latin verb roots which use perfect forms with a present meaning: *meminī*, *ōdī*, and *coepī*. Of these, only *meminī* seems to be attested in the imperative; forms **coeptō(te)* and **ōsō(te)* might be expected, but aren't mentioned in L&S. A corpus search is confounded by the past participles and substantives *coeptus* and *ōsus*, which *meminī* lacks; all instances I have found are from these rather than the imperative.

Other defective verbs are similarly unenlightening. *Āiō* and *inquam* for instance have regular present imperatives, and no attested perfect stems to work from.

Comment: Another place to look might be the perfect system of *nosco*, with its present sense "know"; but here too searching for *noto* turns up lots of false positives.