# Did meminisse ever had a present tense?

Tags: etymology, verbs, irregular-words

The verb *meminī, meminisse, *mementus* ever have any sort of (morphologically) present tense? If not, why not? If so, at what point was it lost in Latin?

Bonus points: if the present tense had survived to Classical Latin, what would it have looked like?

Comment: Similar: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2345/is-mementote-semantically-a-future-imperative